# Get http headers from Guzzle Response Message as string

Tags: php, http, guzzle

After doing an http Request by using Guzzle, I want to print all the response headers. How can I do that?

In the guzzle documentation it is stated that the `getHeaders()` method should be able to cast headers to string, but doing

```php
<?php

    print $response->getHeaders();

?>
```

does not work. It is also stated that in `GuzzleHttp\Message\Response` there should be a method called `getRawHeaders()` that should return the headers as a string, but php tells me that the method is undefined on the Response object. So, how can I accomplish my task of printing all the response headers as a string?

Answer (score 8):

If you would like to see a verbose version of response and request headers with Guzzle 6.0, you need to enable the debug option in your request. For example:

```
$YourGuzzleclient=new Client();
$YourGuzzleclient->request('POST', '{Your url}',
  ['debug'=>true,'otheroptions'=>array()]
);
```

This option will print all the response and request headers. Check the [documentation page](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#debug) where you can find more information.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you will have to iterate through the headers, try this:

```
foreach ($response->getHeaders() as $name => $values) {
    echo $name . ': ' . implode(', ', $values) . "\r\n";
}
```

As per the api (http://api.guzzlephp.org/class-Guzzle.Http.Message.Response.html#_getRawHeaders), you could do:

```
echo $response->getRawHeaders();
```

Comment: He said the function turn headers to string

Comment: i'm quite aware that he said that. I've been looking the Guzzle documentation and it does not say that you can get all headers as a string, you can get a single header if you know the name and it will be a string, but if you get all headers you will get an array of key/value pairs. At least that's what i've read in the documentation.

Comment: Oh ok sorry I didn't check guzzle documentation

Comment: I've found the getRawHeaders method in the api specification (not the documentation) and it says that you can get all headers as a single string. I will update my answer with another solution.

Comment: I saw the getRawHeaders() in the API specification as well, but when I try to use it I get an error saying that the method is not defined on GuzzleHttp\Message\Response. Since I' have to use the string with the header() function, I would prefer to use the getRawHeaders() rather than manually sending each header value and making sure that the final string is http-compliant... Any ideas on how to get that method working?

Comment: The only thing i'm thinking that could be the problem is that the version of your guzzle is not the same as the API specification. But thats just a guess. Seems odd that the API displays a method that is not present in the class, and otherwise should be deprected at least if it was removed.

Comment: @user3075898,@taxicala getRawHeaders was removed [somewhere between](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/003757426cdd50fbad1c34cdbcc8a55f70a4fe8b/UPGRADING.md) v3.7 and v4.0